# How to filter list of objects according to it's property?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to eliminate duplicates based on the properties "name" and "price" of each element and filter the list accordingly.

```dart
List<Connector> connectorList = [
  Model(name : "Type A", price : 2.30, value : "Value 1"),
  Model(name : "Type B", price : 2.30, value : "Value 2"),
  Model(name : "Type C", price : 2.30, value : "Value 3"),
  Model(name : "Type A", price : 2.30, value : "Value 4"),
  Model(name : "Type B", price : 3.30, value : "Value 5"),
  Model(name : "Type B", price : 2.30, value : "Value 6"),
]
```

Output:

```dart
List<Connector> filteredConnectorList = [
  Model(name : "Type A", price : 2.30, value : "Value 1"),
  Model(name : "Type B", price : 2.30, value : "Value 2"),
  Model(name : "Type B", price : 3.30, value : "Value 5"),
  Model(name : "Type C", price : 2.30, value : "Value 3"),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all use `equatable` package to override the `==` operator:

```dart
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Connector with EquatableMixin {
  final String name;
  final double price;
  final String value;

  Connector({
    required this.name,
    required this.price,
    required this.value,
  });

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [name, price];
}
```

Then you can easily use `Set` data structure to achieve your result:

```dart
List<Connector> filteredConnectorList = connectorList.toSet().toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the `collection` package you could do this

```
List<Connector> output = groupBy(connectorList, (e) => (e.name, e.price)).values.map((e) => e.first).toList();
```